# Use public variable in inside function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scope, angular6

I have 2 [slide toggles](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/examples) where I can want to show the status of my panels using [split.js](https://github.com/nathancahill/Split.js).
What I'm trying to achieve is, when I open/close a panel the property `checked` of my slide toggle must be set to true/false.

I have 2 public variables in my component:

```
  public isOverviewVisible: boolean = true;
  public isDetailsVisible: boolean = false
```

Which I use in my html file

```
  <div class="col-auto align-self-end">
    <mat-slide-toggle ngDefaultControl (change)="showOverviewChange($event)" [checked]="isOverviewVisible">
      Show overview
    </mat-slide-toggle>
  </div>
  ...
```

In theconstructor of the component I want to my 2 public variables via the function `onDragEnd` presented by split.js. The debugger steps into this method when I drag the splitter, but the variables `this.isOverviewVisible` and `this.isDetailsVisible` are not the ones I declared as public at the top of my component.

```
    let split = Split(['#overview', '#detail'], {
      onDragEnd: function () {
        let sizes: number[] = split.getSizes();

        if (sizes[0] < 1) {
          this.isOverviewVisible = false;
        } else {
          this.isOverviewVisible = true;
        }
        ...
      }
    });
```

The question is, how can I set my public variables inside the function `onDragEnd`?
Or maybe there is a better way?

**Update**
I changed my code to use the arrow function, but now I get an error on `split.getSizes()` : Property 'getSizes' does not exist on type '() => any'.

```
let split = () => Split(['#overview', '#detail'], {
  sizes: [50, 50],
  minSize: [0, 0],
  direction: 'vertical',
  onDragEnd: function () {
    let sizes: number[] = split.getSizes();
  }
});
```

Comment: Use arrow functions, otherwise `this` will not be what you're expecting. `onDragEnd: () => {`

Comment: Use an arrow function so you don't lose the scope: `onDragEnd:  () => { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
let split = () => Split(['#overview', '#detail'], {
      onDragEnd:  () => {
        let sizes: number[] = split.getSizes();

        if (sizes[0] < 1) {
          this.isOverviewVisible = false;
        } else {
          this.isOverviewVisible = true;
        }
        ...
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, see updated answer. I get a red line under getSizes();

Comment: This is not enough code to say what caused the red line (linter issue, I suppose). Hovering with the mouse on the red line should reveal why that's marked

Comment: The info cause is stated in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an arrow function in your `onDragEnd` function so that `this` is the class instance:

```
    let split = Split(['#overview', '#detail'], {
    onDragEnd: () => {
      let sizes: number[] = split.getSizes();

      if (sizes[0] < 1) {
        this.isOverviewVisible = false;
      } else {
        this.isOverviewVisible = true;
      }
      ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, see updated answer. I get a red line under getSizes();